# Magento 2.1.8: SMTP - Configured store email addresses are not reflecting in the email

Tags: email, order-email, magento-2.1.8, smtp

I'm using Mageplaza SMTP extension to send the emails from my Magento store. I've configured Email Addresses for my Store and also updated sales email configuration. However, when email send upon order placement, it send as Sales (User name is the name I mentioned in my SMTP configuration). The same happening for shipment and other emails. How can I change the from address from username to configured email ID? What am I doing wrong?